# Detect and reject breaking changes to DB Schema

Tags: postgresql, migration, database-migration, backwards-compatibility

Is there a way to detect changes in a DB schema as "breaking changes"?

Imagine I create a migration which adds a column to a table. This is a non-breaking change, and should be allowed.
However, removing a column might break some API or system or whatever and should be rejected (or at least warned about) as a breaking change.

I imagine this has to be a solved problem, but am unable to find tools or features of postgres that auto-detect potentially breaking changes.

Apart from the obivous human code review which could note the change as potentially breaking, I thought of two hacky ways to achieve this:

Create a "test" entry for every table in my DB. On a schema change, try to insert that "test" entry in the altered table. If that does not work (e.g because a column is missing), mark the schema change as breaking. This solution would basically be a test collection with one test per DB table.

Inspect the migration itself, marking the change as breaking if I find words like "DELETE", "ALTER", "DROP" and so on.

Are there more sophisticated approaches to this? Tools/Services that offer this, a postgres feature I dont know about, etc?

Comment: Well, for sure there is no tool that will detect that your api logic is broken due to update on DB unless:
- you use unit test, and you test also DB calls.
- you use code first approach (and if you remove the column, the code will not compile anymore)

Anyways, how do you apply migrations?

Comment: Imagine some third party system uses the DB. I don't want to test whether a schema change breaks that system, I want to make sure a schema change can not break their system. So even if a column is not used by that system, I still want to detect the removal of that column as "breaking change".
Basically testing whether the old schema (schema, not data) is a subset of the new schema.
I don't have a specific stack (migration tool) in mind, but for your questions sake: Assume postgres and alembic

Comment: tl;dr: I want to test the schema, not some dependent system/API.

Comment: There's no "breaking changes" depending on an external system: also when you add a new column, if it is "NOT NULL" will break the logic. 
Even worse: if you add a new foreign key your test may pass and the "external logic" will stop working. That's why there's no tool to perform it, you should write some custom piece of code for that